# Droppoint Error Throws When Testing Sage Evolution Node Connection

Tags: flowgear

I am getting the following error when trying to Test a Sage Evolution connection via a droppoint:

" **DropPoint Invoke Error: Unable to connect to database - This Node does not support Sage Evolution v7.20.2.000. Try upgrading the Node.**"

Past this connection via droppoint is working fine but when i have upgrade sage version v7.0 to v7.20 and when testing sage evolution connection it is throws this error.My sage evolution node version is v7.0.0.61.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've updated the Sage Evolution node to support the latest SDK version.
Update the node vers

Comment: Okay thanks,I have upgrade my sage evolution node and test connection but its give the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

Comment: @sanjay you can try that again now

Comment: I have tried again but no luck it is given same error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when test sage evolution connection(my sage evolution node version is now 7.20.0.0). or when i run only sage evolution node connected by start node and hit run button it is throws error "Unable to instance node PastelEvolution 7.20.0.0: Unable to cast object of type 'flowgear.Nodes.PastelEvolution.PastelEvolution' to type 'flowgear.Sdk.INode'."

Comment: @Sanjay - We are aware of the connection test issue and are working on it. Install the latest version of the DropPoint to fix the second error